# pod_number_of_container_restarts Container Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

`pod_number_of_container_restarts` is defined as:

> The total number of container restarts in a pod.

However, when trying to test this metric via Metrics in CloudWatch:

By doing `kubectl -n Namespace123  rollout restart deployment test123`

And then watching the query

```
SELECT SUM(pod_number_of_container_restarts) FROM SCHEMA(ContainerInsights,
ClusterName,FullPodName,Namespace,PodName)
WHERE ClusterName='Cluster123' AND Namespace ='Namespace123'
```

I do not see any pod restarts, this number is just forever at 0.

[image]

Container Insights is definitely installed on this EKS cluster. Am I missing a config somewhere? Or am I triggering restarted pods the right way this metric was designed to detect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollout restart triggers deletion of of existing **pod** and replace with new **pod**, this is not restart of container *within* a pod which `pod_number_of_container_restarts` tracks.

Comment: Is there a way I can test triggering `pod_number_of_container_restarts` then?

Would `kubectl exec <pod_name> -c <container_name> -- /bin/sh -c "kill 1"` work?

Comment: You can test with Pod `restartPolicy: Always` with a command like `sh -c 'sleep 3; exit 1'`